# How to drag and drop list using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to reorder a list which is coming from database as follows. I'm calling an api which gives me the required data and i bind it to html page via angularjs controller.

```
    <ul ui-sortable class="sortable list">
        <li ng-repeat="y in stagelist">{{y.stageName}}

            <span style="float:right;margin-right:10px;">

                <a href="#" ng-click="deletestage(y.id)"><img src="~/Images/delete.png" /></a> &emsp;
                <img src="~/Images/sortarrow.png" />
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

In my controller I have:

```
    Method.getbyId("stages", _job.JobId).then(function (list) {
        $scope.stagelist = list.data;}).catch(function (data) {
        console.log("access not allowed");
    });
```

I'm not able to move any list item up or down. Please help. I've included Angular.Ui.Sortable both in nuget and bower packages.

At the end I actually want to reorder the list and sent it back on button click to server where it should update the order of the list.

Comment: can you please show us the `data` coming from the `server`, and what field are you trying to re-order it on?

Comment: data is stagename with orderNo. i want to reorder the list in the UI and then send back the list with new orderNo(that includes condition that any list item can be deleted and the consecutive items to be ordered up respectively).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this website https://www.webucator.com/blog/2016/10/drag-drop-sortable-angularjs-angular-ui-sortable/   to use the drag and drop model to work. Then I used required model using ui.item.sortable.droptargetModel to do my stuff.